# jquery autosuggest creating wrong url request

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, autocomplete

I have an auto suggest code with jquery and php, the issue is the jquery is sending ajax request for which the browser is responding with 400(bad request)
The problem is the query should have been generated like

```
http://localhost/abc/index.php?/controller/autoComplete**?q=a**&limit=5&timestamp=1382
```

but the request is generated like

```
http://localhost/abc/index.php?/controller/autoComplete **&q=a**&limit=5&timestamp=1382
```

The autocomplete function is like

```
$.fn.extend({
autocomplete: function(urlOrData, options) {
var isUrl = typeof urlOrData == "string";
options = $.extend({}, $.Autocompleter.defaults, {
    url: isUrl ? urlOrData : null,
    data: isUrl ? null : urlOrData,
delay: isUrl ? $.Autocompleter.defaults.delay : 10,
max: options && !options.scroll ? 5 : 5
}, options);
```

The code that invokes the function in view which has text field with id = 'search'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").autocomplete("<?php echo "http://localhost/abc/index.php?/controller/autoComplete"; ?>", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
```

Where autocomplete is the function in controller
I made a change in the config.php of my code igniter i changed

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
```

Comment: try placing a backslash(\) before ? when you are concatenating or you can also do http://localhost/abc/index.php?/controller/autoComplete\\";  the two backslashes at the end

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL , at te line of inclusion of backslash

Comment: if its a complete php string you can use str_replace to replace &q with ?q, just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I guess the url is formatted like this because you already have a ? sign in your url. Other parameters will be seperated with an & sign

Comment: ya i understand that can anybody tell how to rectify that problem ?

Comment: Removing the ? sign from the `<?php echo "http://localhost/abc/index.php?/controller/autoComplete"; ?>` line would solve it. When you post the data to index.php the URL would become `localhost/abc/index.php?q=a&limit=5&timestamp=1382`. I guess you could also use `localhost/abc/controller/autoComplete?q=a&limit=5&timestamp=1382`?

Comment: if i give without the '?' with index.php then my godaddy server says no input file specified

Answer (score 0):

did you try a backslash **** with **?**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").autocomplete("<?php echo "http://localhost/abc/index.php\?/controller/autoComplete"; ?>", {
        selectFirst: true
    });
});
```